# Can't get nginx to serve collected static files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, static-files

I am trying to get nginx to work alongside gunicorn. I have a directory `/project/static/` where static files are. Those files are collected into a directory `/project/livestatic/` using the `settings.py` configuration shown:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/project/livestatic'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/project/static',
)
```

I'm using the following nginx config:

```
worker_processes 1;
user nobody nogroup;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/nginx.error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;
    sendfile on;

    upstream app_server {
        server 127.0.0.1 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name domain.org;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        # path for static files
        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            root /var/www/startupsearch_live/livestatic/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        }
    }
}
```

Under the development server (ignoring nginx), this configuration works fine and I can serve static files by linking to them in the format `/static/file.extension`. However, the moment nginx/gunicorn come into play, this doesn't work, and attempting to access `domain.org/static/` gives a django 404 page, signifying that nginx straight up isn't serving the files at all. How have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question gets asked quite a lot on here...

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/startupsearch_live/livestatic/;
}
```

Using `root` the way you had it would make a request for `/static/foo.jpg` resolve to `/var/www/startupsearch_live/livestatic/static/foo.jpg`

`alias` doesn't append the location to it. It one-for-one maps it as-is.

Comment: I did some research before asking; this doesn't work for some reason. I'm still getting a Django 404 even after restarting gunicorn and reloading nginx
, so it seems to be that the `location /` setting is somehow overriding the `location /static/`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Update: turns out a system reboot fixed it... I'll mark your answer as correct since I'm guessing I would have encountered that problem later on either way.

Comment: @RandallMa even 9 years later, the simple reboot has solved the same problem in my project

Comment: A reboot is not the fix, but a method which applies it.